Error decoding .mov file on ios and macos - DOMException when processing audio data in React app
I am working on a React application that processes video files and extracts audio for analysis. The app works well on most platforms, but when I try to upload and process a .mov file on an iPhone and on mac, I encounter the following errors:
Error decoding audio data: DOMException
Error processing file: DOMException

How it works:

A video file is uploaded.

The video file is converted to an array buffer.

The array buffer is passed to the decodeAudioData function of the Web Audio API to extract audio data.


Below is part of my code
const extractAudioFromVideo = async (file) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function () {
      const arrayBuffer = reader.result;

      audioContext.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer).then((decodedAudioData) => {
        const offlineAudioContext = new OfflineAudioContext(
          decodedAudioData.numberOfChannels,
          decodedAudioData.duration * decodedAudioData.sampleRate,
          decodedAudioData.sampleRate
        );
        const soundSource = offlineAudioContext.createBufferSource();
        soundSource.buffer = decodedAudioData;
        soundSource.connect(offlineAudioContext.destination);
        soundSource.start();

        offlineAudioContext.startRendering().then((renderedBuffer) => {
          const wavBlob = audioBufferToWav(renderedBuffer);
          resolve(wavBlob);
        }).catch((err) => {
          console.error('Error during offline audio rendering:', err);
          reject(err);
        });
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.error('Error decoding audio data:', err);
        reject(err);
      });
    };

    reader.onerror = function (err) {
      console.error('Error reading file:', err);
      reject(err);
    };

    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  });
};

this is the audioBufferToWav
  const audioBufferToWav = (buffer) => {
    const numOfChan = buffer.numberOfChannels,
      length = buffer.length * numOfChan * 2 + 44,
      bufferArray = new ArrayBuffer(length),
      view = new DataView(bufferArray),
      channels = [],
      sampleRate = buffer.sampleRate;

    let offset = 0;
    let pos = 0;

    setUint32(0x46464952); // "RIFF"
    setUint32(length - 8); // file length - 8
    setUint32(0x45564157); // "WAVE"

    setUint32(0x20746d66); // "fmt " chunk
    setUint32(16); // length = 16
    setUint16(1); // PCM (uncompressed)
    setUint16(numOfChan);
    setUint32(sampleRate);
    setUint32(sampleRate * 2 * numOfChan); // avg. bytes/sec
    setUint16(numOfChan * 2); // block-align
    setUint16(16); // 16-bit (hardcoded in this demo)

    setUint32(0x61746164); // "data" - chunk
    setUint32(length - pos - 4); // chunk length

    for (let i = 0; i < buffer.numberOfChannels; i++) {
      channels.push(buffer.getChannelData(i));
    }

    while (pos < length) {
      for (let i = 0; i < numOfChan; i++) {
        const sample = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, channels[i][offset])); // clamp
        view.setInt16(pos, sample < 0 ? sample * 0x8000 : sample * 0x7FFF, true); // write 16-bit sample
        pos += 2;
      }
      offset++;
    }

    return new Blob([bufferArray], { type: "audio/wav" });

    function setUint16(data) {
      view.setUint16(pos, data, true);
      pos += 2;
    }

    function setUint32(data) {
      view.setUint32(pos, data, true);
      pos += 4;
    }
  };

What could be causing this DOMException error, and how can I resolve it?
Additional Information:

The issue is specific to .mov files on iPhones.

Other video formats and platforms work fine.


github link:
https://github.com/elderbug0/nfac-project-frontend/blob/master/src/App.js

ReferenceError: audioBufferToWav is not defined

Sorry, It was defined but i did not wrote it here, i updated the code

Try to Debug iOS Safari from your Mac https://www.busbud.com/blog/debug-ios-safari-mac/

I made your code works ok in my macOS in both Chrome and Safari using .webm extension.
But in the iPhone debugging like in the previous link that I posted i get the following errors:
Error decoding audio data: - EncodingError: Decoding failed
Unhandled Promise Rejection: EncodingError: Decoding failed

I added the github link to the whole code, you would like to see it

I will check the code you stored in github.

I tried your code in iPhone Safari and get this error: TypeError: Argument 1 ('blob') to FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer must be an instance of Blob in App.js line 89

The same error is also inside the function pollAudioProcessingStatus.

Yeah, there are problems with decoding the mov file, i dont know why as it works fine with other types of the files

I place comments where the previous errors happened and tried also with an .mp4 but the code inside; reader.onload = function () is never called.

What can i do to solve this?

I have discovered what could be the cause of the error in iOS. In iOS the handleSubmit function is called automatically when you "click to select a file", without even needing to click the "Upload Your Video" button. At the time the form is sent, no file is still selected.

I tried to modify it, but is is still giving me decoding error
